# C++ Initialize nested struct in constructor's initialization list?

Tags: c++, struct, constructor, initialization

```
  struct B
  {

    int hh;
    int ii;
  };          

  struct A
  {
    B b_memberVar;
    void *p_data;
  };

  struct C
  {
    A array[13];
    int bb;
    int cc;
    int dd;
    int ee;
    int ff;
    int gg;
  };

  struct D
  {
    C c_memberVar;
    int aa;
  };

  class XYZ
  {
    XYZ();
    D m_DMemberVar;
    int zz;
  }

  XYZ::XYZ():
    m_DMemberVar(
    ({{{
            {{0,0},nullptr},
            {{0,0},nullptr},
            {{0,0},nullptr},
            {{0,0},nullptr},
            {{0,0},nullptr},
            {{0,0},nullptr},
            {{0,0},nullptr},
            {{0,0},nullptr},
            {{0,0},nullptr},
            {{0,0},nullptr},
            {{0,0},nullptr},
            {{0,0},nullptr},
            {{0,0},nullptr}
            },0,0,0,0,0,0},0}),
            zz(0)
    ){}
```

How do I initialize a nested struct that's a class member variable on the constructor's initialization list?
I have tried using a lot of nested {} as shown as an example above but that produced syntax errors. 
The errors give "expected an expression" and "expected a ")" "

Comment: `({{..,..},{..},..)` is definitely a syntax error (among other bugs) - can you show us your actual [MCVE]?

Comment: Firstly, your code lacks the `XYZ()` declaration, `{}` after `XYZ()` defintion; some `;`s are missing, and structs are in the wrong order. After I fixed that, `{...}` syntax worked for me. Post your *actual* code.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, Apologies for the crude code. I was trying to keep it very simple. I have fixed it.

Comment: Looks like a typo to me. You wrote `XYZ() : m_DMemberVar( ({...}), zz(0) )`. It should be `XYZ() : m_DMemberVar({...}), zz(0) {}` instead. To make the code compile, you also need to add a missing `;` after `class XYZ`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat In actuality, the structs reside in different locations. They seem to be out of order because I copied them from their respective locations. The compilation is fine. Also, the missing {} is actually a typo from when I posted the question.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you have a ton of errors with your class definitions:

- Wrong order and no forward declarations
- Missing semicolon terminators
- Missing constructor declaration
- Missing constructor definition body
- Sample/placeholder initialiser invalid

But, once those are fixed, it really is just a case of matching your braces.

Here we go!

```
struct D
{
 int D_MemberVar;
};

struct C
{
 int* c_ptrMemberVar;
};

struct B
{
 C c_memberVar;
 D* d_ptrMemberVar;
};

struct A
{
 B b_memberVar;
 int int_memberVar;
};

class XYZ
{
 A m_memberVar;
 int z;

public:
 XYZ();
};

XYZ::XYZ()
    : m_memberVar{
        {    // A::b_memberVar
            {   // B::c_memberVar
                nullptr    // B::c_ptrMemberVar
            },
            nullptr  // B::d_ptrMemberVar
        },
        3    // A::int_memberVar
    }
    , z(0)
{}

int main()
{
    XYZ xyz;
}
```

#### ([live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/01a39b5e9b6a0bc8))

I suspect the key is that you were trying to use `A`'s constructor, but there is no non-default constructor in that class. So you needed `{}` at the top level too.